# Does my linear model with variable hidden layers look okay? [Pytorch]

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I just need some help as I am getting very high loss values and this is the first model ive created myself so not sure if its my model or input data that is the cause.

My code is below

```
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, D_in, H, D_out,num_layers,dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.fcs = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(D_in, H)])
        for k in range(num_layers-1):
            self.fcs.append(nn.Linear(H, H))
            
        self.fcs.append(nn.Linear(H, D_out))
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
      
        for l in self.fcs:
            x = self.dropout(x) 
            x = self.relu(l(x))

        return x.squeeze()
```

Comment: post your code as a text not as an image

Comment: sorry just realized that there, that should be it.

Comment: I'm not spotting any obvious mistake in this code. To clarify: Is your loss just very high at the start, or does it also not improve when you train more? Is the training loss still bad if you don't use `dropout`?